# Pass through a mandatory parameters in my Behat scenario

Tags: symfony, testing, routes, bdd, behat

I am trying to determine how to pass through a mandatory parameter required to follow a defined route within my Behat features file.

This is my scenario:

```
Scenario: I should be able to create a cars asset
    Given I am on the ayrshireminis_cars_asset_create page
    When I submit a "ayrshireminis.cars.asset.type" form with values:
        | name               | type | position | active |
        | Cars Info Doc      | PDF  | 1        | 1      |
    Then The form should be valid
```

and this is the error:

> Given I am on the ayrshireminis_cars_asset_create page
>         Some mandatory parameters are missing ("categoryId") to generate a URL for route "ayrshireminis_cars_asset_create".
>   (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException)

It's clear why I get this error as my routing is configured like this:

```
ayrshireminis_cars_asset_create:
    pattern: /category/{categoryId}/asset/new/
```

How can I pass through a `categoryId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was looking at this from the wrong angle, this is how I constructed the test scenario in the end up:

```
Scenario: Submitting a valid cars asset form
    When I submit a "ayrshireminis.cars.cars_asset.type" form with values:
        | name               | type | position | active |
        | Cars Info Doc      | pdf  | 1        | 1      |
    Then  the form should be valid
    And   the cars entity form entity should have the following values
        | name               | type | position | active |
        | Cars Info Doc      | pdf  | 1        | 1      |
    And   the cars entity form entity should be persisted correctly
```